# how to use if condition in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I had placed `div` with condition.. on my execution,if condition is also displayed,        i need to remove it..

```
        **My New Code**

<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="90px" ItemStyle-Width="0">
    <ItemTemplate>  

        <div style="cursor: pointer; padding-top: 02px;" onclick="ShowfllDetails(<%#Eval("StudentID")%>);">

        if(<%# (Eval("StatusName").Equals("Processed")) %>)
        {
            //should not show the upload button                   
        }
        else
        {
         <u>Upload </u> //show the upload button
        }
        </div>

        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#(Eval("StatusName").Equals("Processed") ? "images/add_btn.png" : "")%>' />

    </ItemTemplate>
```

[image]
I'm getting displayed the if condition i need not to display it..

Thank-You.

Comment: i'm un aware of jquery can you suggest me how to carry over it..

Comment: use fiddle post your html here http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have done such a functionality inside Gridview, I assume you are doing the same. In place of   tag you can use linkbutton set commandArgument and Commandname properties. AFter that fire Gridview_Rowcommand event. when ever you will click on linkbutton this event will fire and you can set the status in database or somewhere in session that this link is clicked against student id

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Upload" CommandName="Upload"
                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("StudentID")%>'></asp:LinkButton>

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Upload")
    {
        // get student id against clicked link button
        int studentid = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument);
        // -- set status in database it is clicked
    }
}
```

after this bind your grid and on rowdatabound find control and set the visibility to true or false (Processed/Not Processed)

Bind your "StatusName" database field to a label and set the visibility to false of Label so that it should not display.

**Now take idea from following code**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Display the company name in italics.
        Label lblAssignto = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblassignto");
        LinkButton addevent = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkBtnAddEvent");
        LinkButton showevent = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkBtnShowEvent");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblAssignto.Text))
        {
            addevent.Visible = false;
            showevent.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            addevent.Visible = true;
            showevent.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not need your if(<%# Eval("StatusName").Equals("Processed"))%>) scripts inside template just shift code to your code behine as suggested

Comment: I suppose upload is a "Button" or "LinkButton". You can fire a rowdatabound of gridview and then find the control. Basis on "StatusName" you can do it.